# What is wrong with this function that is supposed to listen to an event from a smart contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, events, logs

I am essentially just trying to create a simple API that listens to this one event on a smart contract I created but for some reason the function doesn't output anything. I am pretty sure it has something to do with how my event is setup in the contract because when I use the same format for an event from another contract it works fine. I'll add screenshots of what the event looks like and the current function I am fiddling with, any suggestions are appreciated.
[image: The event in the smart contract.]

[image: The part of the function that isn't working.]

Here is the entire file that is supposed to be listening to the event:

```
const contractABI = require("../ABIs/ABI_TEST_1.json");   
require('dotenv').config();

const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS;


async function main() {

    const alchemyProvider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
        `wss://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/2weKkQ426LualTuW1XrCkDRyOOj284BH`
    );

    const profReviewContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, contractABI, alchemyProvider);


    // I still haven't gotten this to work
    profReviewContract.on("UpdateReviews", (newReviews, newRating, event) => {
        let info = { 
            newReviews,
            newRating,
            event
        };

        console.log(JSON.stringify(info, null, 3));
    });

}

main()
```

Comment: Can you share more of the js/ts code? Specifically how the profReviewContract instance is initialised. Also use markdown code blocks instead of screenshots.